# cambiar for por forEach

Tags: script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Soy nuevo en esto y quiero optimizar el siguiente codigo porque se demora muchos segundos en la ejecucion, tengo un sheets en google que tiene estos campos Carpeta Grados, Id Carpeta Grados, Carpeta Cursos y Id Carpeta Cursos, en la segunda columna tengo un id de donde quiero que me cree la carpeta, el codigo ya me funciona pero se demora mucho en ejecutar.

```
    function carpetaCursos() {
       for (var i = 2; i < filas + 1; i++) {
    var grado = hoja.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var carpetaGrado = hoja.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var nombreCurso = hoja.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var carpetaCurso = DriveApp.createFolder(nombreCurso);

    var cursoId = carpetaCurso.getId();
    var carpetaGradoId = DriveApp.getFolderById(carpetaGrado);

    hoja.getRange(i, 4).setValue(cursoId);

    carpetaCurso.moveTo(carpetaGradoId);
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué te hace pensar que cambiar un `for` por un `foreach` va a optimizar el código?

Comment: Segun estuve leyendo en varias fuentes, eso hace porque recorre los datos por medio de arreglos, hace una sola lectura y luego ahi si escribe en los campos que se requiere, pero no estoy seguro si es asi.